# Sub group Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a sub gruop from a query using nodejs and mongoose. 
The thing I'm trying to do is the following: 
I have this collection: 
[image]
[image]

I Need to count and group all the documents with the same 'intent' and make a subgroup with the 'entity' value, so far I have this running: 
try {

```
    //We first get the total interactions from all workspace
    let workspace = await Interaction.aggregate([
        { $match: { dateAdded: { $gte: todayStart, $lt: todayEnd }, workspace: workspaceID } },
        { $group: { _id: "$workspace", data: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
    ]).exec();

    //We then get the total results from conversations
    let results = await Interaction.aggregate([
        { $match: { dateAdded: { $gte: todayStart, $lt: todayEnd }, workspace: workspaceID } },
        { $group: { _id: '$intent', data: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
    ]).exec()
     //workspaceItems = workspace.map(function (Interaction) { return Interaction._id; });

    return res.json({
        total: workspace,
        result: results
    })

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send(err)
}
```

**The result look like this:**

```
{
"total": [
    {
        "_id": "Business",
        "data": 23
    }
],
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "N/A",
        "data": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "PRODUCTO_BENEFICIOS",
        "data": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": "PRODUCTO_DESCRIPCION",
        "data": 10
    },
    {
        "_id": "REPORTE_TARJETA_PERDIDA",
        "data": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "REQUISITOS",
        "data": 7
    }
]
```

}

**I need the result in this way :**

```
{
"total": [
    {
        "_id": "Business",
        "data": 23
    }
],
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "N/A",
        "data": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "PRODUCTO_BENEFICIOS",
        "entities: [{"TARJETAS","PROMOCIONES"."ETC..."}],
        "data": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": "PRODUCTO_DESCRIPCION",
        "entities: [{"TARJETAS","PROMOCIONES"."ETC..."}],
        "data": 10
    },
    {
        "_id": "REPORTE_TARJETA_PERDIDA",
        "entities: [{"TARJETAS","PROMOCIONES"."ETC..."}],
        "data": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": "REQUISITOS",
        "entities: [{"TARJETAS","PROMOCIONES"."ETC..."}],
        "data": 7
    }
]
```

}

I Hope to be clear, please let me know if you know how to do this using mongoose.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the 2nd query to following

```
let results = await Interaction.aggregate([
    { $match: { dateAdded: { $gte: todayStart, $lt: todayEnd }, workspace: workspaceID } },
    { $group: { _id: '$intent', entities: {$push: "$entity"}, data: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
]).exec()
```

if you want a unique list of entities you can use `$addToSet` instead of `$push`